# Start container instance on web request to FQDN

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

Let's say we have a (containerized) backend which is only sparely used. Maybe once every couple of days or so, a (static) web front-end calls an API endpoint of that backend.

The backend conveniently happens to be stateless. No data store or anything.

We want to minimize the hosting cost for it, and ideally would like per-second billing. It's only gonna be running for a few minutes every month, and we only want to be charged for that usage. Basically, we want Function as a Service (FaaS), but for a whole backend and not just a single function.

Azure Container Instances appears to be great fit for this scenario. It can spin up the backend in a container when needed. The backend then can shut itself down again after a certain period of non-usage.

So, let's create a container instance...

```
az container create \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name mycontainer \
    --image mycontainerimage \
    --restart-policy Never
    --dns-name-label mybackend123 
    --ports 80
```

Great, our backend is live at its FQDN `http://mybackend123.eastus.azurecontainer.io`!

As stated above, it'll shut itself down after a period of non-usage. Thanks to `--restart-policy Never`, ACI won't restart the container but keep it around in status `Stopped`.

My question is: **is there any way to automatically start the container again if a web request to the FQDN arrives?**

Sure, we can wake it up ourselves by running...

```
az container start --resource-group myResourceGroup --name mycontainer
```

... or with an equivalent API call. But then the service that does *that* needs to be running all the time! Ideally, I'd like the container to start itself whenever a request comes in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Container Instances don't have a wehbook or HTTP trigger that will start them. However, you could use an Azure Function or Logic App that would effectively run `az container start` for you and then call THAT with HTTP. With either of those approaches, you'd have to setup some IAM permissions to give the Function or Logic App permissions to the ACI resource to start it.

One approach would be to:

1. Create an Azure Function with an HTTP trigger and a managed identity
2. Give the Managed identity contributor access to ACI container group
3. Run `az container start` or the equivalent REST call inside the function to start the ACI container
4. Call the Azure function (using the function token) to start the container.

Comment: I was about to type the same but @BrandonOlin beat me to it, so I thought I'd just add as a comment. You could create a function running on a consumption plan to start and then call the ACI. Alternatively just run the container itself in a function, but to do that you won't be able to run it on a consumption plan. But you can run it on a low cost app service plan, which isn't free (can't use free tier for containers), but would be cheap.

Comment: Yep, running a container inside the function is another option as well!

Comment: can someone post an example code in c# please? @BrandonOlin

Comment: @IraRainey can you please post some example code in C#?